# Unable to deploy docker image from intellij plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, docker

I am using intellij 2016.1 and docker plugin 2.1.4.
I am trying to deploy a simple java container to a remote machine and get error:

> Failed to deploy 'gaia-itest  Image Id:
>   gaiaadm/gaia-integration-tests': javax.websocket.DeploymentException:
>   The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed

This is the output from the deploy log:

```
Deploying 'gaia-itest  Image Id: gaiaadm/gaia-integration-tests'...
Creating container...
Container Id: 71afc5f10a0779639543bb7c74235f507d59e24890e66d01fe17a7f90cccc301
Starting container 'gaia-itest'
Attaching to container 'gaia-itest'...
Failed to deploy 'gaia-itest  Image Id: gaiaadm/gaia-integration-tests': javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.3.3-jdk-8

# Bundle app source
COPY . /src

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /src

LABEL test=
LABEL test.run.interval=300000

CMD ["mvn","clean","install"]
```

and container_settings:

```
{
  "_comment": "gaia-itest",
  "Image": "gaiaadm/gaia-integration-tests",
  "ExposedPorts": {
    "22/tcp": {}
  },
  "AttachStdin": true,
  "OpenStdin": true,
  "HostConfig": {
    "Links":["sts:sts", "whs:whs"],
    "PortBindings":{
      "22/tcp": [{ "HostIp": "0.0.0.0", "HostPort": "2221" }]},
    "RestartPolicy": { "Name": "on-failure", "MaximumRetryCount": 5 }
  }
}
```

I have a connection to the docker machine, I can access docker API remotely from the browser and docker ports are open...
I can even see the list of containers running from intellij and I see my container, it is just the deployment that is failing.

Any idea what can be the issue?